# Control media on PlayStation 3 from a PC?

Tags: ps3, media-server, ps3-media-server

I have the following:

- PC
- PlayStation 3 hooked up to a receiver and speakers

Currently I can set up a media server on my PC and choose songs on the PS3 to play.

However, I'd like to be able to control the songs that are played via my pc.  So basically I want to stream music to my PS3 (as usual), but rather than selecting the song through the PS3 media browser, I want to be able to select and play the song from my PC.
Is this possible with my current setup?  Is there software or hardware that I can get that will allow me to achieve this?  A wireless solution would be ideal (the use-case is that when I am on the computer in the other room I'd like to be able to control, from the PC, the music streaming to my PS3 as I can still hear it all throughout the house).

**EDIT**: seems like the Apple AirPort will allow me to do this via iTunes.  However, I'd still love an option using the PC and the PS3.  Or possibly a non-Apple (so I'm not stuck with iTunes) alternative.

**EDIT 2**:  Doing some more research, it seems that there are options to do this from an android or iphone (neither of which I have).  If its possible from these mobile devices I'm thinking there has to be a solution for the pc?  Or maybe no-one has developed this feature?

Comment: Yep, I have 2Player on my Android phone for this purpose. I would imagine you could get a PC app for this but I haven't done any Googling.

Comment: Can the PS3 connect to a Shoutcast stream?  If so, Winamp might be an option.

Answer (score 1):

your windows machine and especially the windows-media-center stuff is just fine for streaming stuff from your pc to the ps3. the missing part is how you control the ps3 to play the stuff you want to play.

i know that sony's vaio laptops come with software which allows the user to control their ps3 from the laptop. there are hacks to use that software to achieve the same:

http://www.engadget.com/2010/06/18/developer-gets-sonys-remote-play-working-on-non-vaio-machines/

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/7225/playstation-3-use-remote-play-on-any-non-sony-vaio-windows-7-pc-ps3-firmware-3-30/

Comment: One of those Articles is for firmware 3.30. We are on 3.70, beware

Comment: "PS3 firmware 3.30+" .. 'plus' meaning 'at least'. reason for that is that sony delivered the remote-play-stuff for non-psps with firmware 3.30, afaik.